# How to roll one dice at a time?

Tags: javascript, dice

So here is what I have so far. I am very new to javascript. How do I make these dice roll sequentially inside of the divs? Such as only displaying the next random number only after the first one is displayed.

```
<html>
<style>
.numdiv{
height: 400px;
width: 200px;
border:solid 1px green; 
float: left
}
</style>

<head>
<script>
function rollDice(){
var number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("number2");
var number3 = document.getElementById("number3");
var status = document.getElementById("status");
var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var d3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var diceTotal = d1 + d2 + d3;

    number1.innerHTML = d1;
    number2.innerHTML = d2;
    number3.innerHTML = d3;
    status.innerHTML = "You rolled "+diceTotal+".";
    if(diceTotal == 15){
        status.innerHTML += "You Win!!";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="numdiv" id="number1">

0</div>
<div class="numdiv"  id="number2">
0</div>
<div class="numdiv"  id="number3">
0</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button onclick="rollDice()"/>Generate Number</button></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><span id="status">0</span></td></tr>
</table>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Set a delay between `innerHTML` assignment, with something like `setTimeout`

Comment: let me rephrase, I only want the dice to advance and show the next one after I click generate number again.

Comment: Do you want a time delay, or to wait until the button is pressed again?

Comment: Wait until pressed again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a counter variable starting with one outside of your rollDice function and every time that is clicked then increase the counter by one. Then you need to replace all the number variables with just this:

```
var number = document.getElementById("number" + counter);
```

I think you know where to go from here. Let me know if you need more guidance!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`setTimeout()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to delay execution of a function, so that the dice will be rolled one at a time:

```js
function rollDice(){
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var nums = document.querySelectorAll(".numdiv");
  var diceTotal = 0;
  var current;
  
  for (current = 0; current < nums.length; current++) {
    nums[current].innerHTML = "?";
  }
  
  current = 0;
  status.innerHTML = "Rolling...";
  
  function rollNext() {
    currentRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    nums[current].innerHTML = currentRoll;
    diceTotal += currentRoll;
    current++;
    if (current < nums.length) {
      setTimeout(rollNext, 1000);
    } else {
      status.innerHTML = "You rolled " + diceTotal + ".";
      if(diceTotal == 15){
        status.innerHTML += "You Win!!";
      }    
    }
  }
  setTimeout(rollNext, 1000);
}
```

```css
.numdiv { height: 30px; width: 30px; border:solid 1px green; float: left; margin: 10px }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="numdiv" id="number1"></div>
    <div class="numdiv"  id="number2"></div>
    <div class="numdiv"  id="number3"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button onclick="rollDice()"/>Generate Number</button></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td><span id="status">0</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Notice also that I've removed your separate `number1`, `number2` and `number3` variables, instead using a single variable `num` to refer to the list of all of the `.numDiv` div elements. That way you can easily change how many dice you want to use without changing the JS at all (you'd just add or remove `.numDiv` elements).

**EDIT:** As I was posting the above you clarified that you want the user to press the button for each die, not automatically roll all three with a delay. So I guess, maybe something like the following, keeping a counter and the total in variables declared *outside* the function:

```js
  var statusSpan = document.getElementById("status");
  var nums = document.querySelectorAll(".numdiv");
  var diceTotal;
  var current = 0;

  function rollDice(){
    if (current === 0) { // reset display
      for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        nums[i].innerHTML = "?";
      diceTotal = 0;
    }
    
    currentRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    nums[current].innerHTML = currentRoll;
    diceTotal += currentRoll;
    if (++current < nums.length) {
      statusSpan.innerHTML = "Current total: " + diceTotal + ".";
    } else {
      statusSpan.innerHTML = "You rolled " + diceTotal + ".";
      if(diceTotal == 15){
        statusSpan.innerHTML += "You Win!!";
      }
      current = 0;
    }
  }
```

```css
.numdiv { height: 30px; width: 30px; border:solid 1px green; float: left; margin: 10px; text-align: center }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="numdiv" id="number1"></div>
    <div class="numdiv"  id="number2"></div>
    <div class="numdiv"  id="number3"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button onclick="rollDice()">Roll next die</button></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td><span id="status">Ready to roll?</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems like the OP wants something different :) *let me rephrase, I only want the dice to advance and show the next one after I click generate number again.*

Comment: @AndrewL. - Ah. They posted that clarification about three seconds before I posted my answer. Maybe I'll edit.

Comment: Yes! @Jlouk — `var ndivs = document.getElementsByClassName('numdiv')` gives you all of the _numdiv_ divs, and `var maxrolls = ndivs.length` tells you how many there are. Then you can roll your die (or dice) that many times, once after each click, stopping when you've hit the max.

Comment: @Jlouk - I've updated my answer to do one roll per click, automatically restarting if the user keeps clicking after rolling all dice.

Answer (score 0):

Building on your existing logic, if you want to display 1 every time user clicks then an alternate approach....

```
    var totalIter = 0;//global var which is set to increments on each click
    var diceTotal = 0;

    function rollDice() {
        totalIter = totalIter + 1; //increment by 1
        //Existing logic from your script
        var ele = document.getElementById("number" + totalIter);
        var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        diceTotal = diceTotal + d1;
        ele.innerHTML = d1;
        status.innerHTML = "You rolled " + diceTotal + ".";
        if (diceTotal == 15) {
            status.innerHTML += "You Win!!";
        }
    }
```